# Image randomizer that sends the current selected image trough intent

Tags: android, android-intent, imagebutton

I have a image randomizer on an imagebutton. But I can't send the current loaded image as an intent when using this imagebutton.

1st Activity

```
    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

    imageButton.buildDrawingCache();
    final Bitmap bitmap = imageButton.getDrawingCache();

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
            intentLoadNewActivity.putExtra ("BitmapImage", bitmap);
            startActivity(intentLoadNewActivity);
        }
```

2nd Activity

```
ImageView iv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);

    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");

    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
```

Comment: What exactly are struggling with? Getting the current random image from the button, sending the intent? Please [edit] your question, clarify what exactly you're struggling with and why and share the relevant parts of your current code.

Comment: Not able to give it at the moment, when I'm able ill edit. For now feel free to check my re-edited question.

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: Well my build runs. But the image isn't shown in the image view in the 2nd activity. So I presume I'm missing some assignment.

Comment: Where your images come from ? Drawable ? Assets ? External ? Can you just pass the resource ID or the url ? Would be easier...

Comment: The images come from my drawable folder. image = R.drawable.image...
How can I pass the resource ID because this can vary on the outcome of my random image generator.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me.

1st Activity

```
    imageButton.setImageResource(images[pickedImage])
```

this specefies the random image

```
    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);


    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
//this is basically the solution
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("image",(images[pickedImage]));
            intentLoadNewActivity.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intentLoadNewActivity);
        }
```

2nd Activity

```
    ImageView iv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);

    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);

    Bundle bundle=this.getIntent().getExtras();
    int pic=bundle.getInt("image");
    iv.setImageResource(pic);
}
```